# How to ignore a Syntax Error without correcting the code?

Tags: vba, excel, syntax, error-handling, syntax-error

This is my first question at stackoverflow and I hope you can help me.
On a big work project, I have to import some VBA codes (that are written on *.txt files), test them and run them if they're working properly.
The problem is that some of that codes have Syntax errors like the one next:

```
Sub ExampleScript()

    Dim variable as Double
    MsgBox variable +

End sub
```

Sure, I know that the code line `MsgBox variable +` is going to originate an error and pop up the warning

How do I get rid of the warning? Just by ignoring it? I tried already commands like `On Error Resume Next` or `On Error GoTo...` but simply can't fix the problem

```
Sub ExampleScript()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim variable as Double
    MsgBox variable +

End sub
```

or

```
Sub ExampleScript()
    On Error GoTo Debugs
    Dim variable as Double
    MsgBox variable +
Debugs:
End sub
```

Note please that my question is about simply ignore the errors (by moving forward or ending the sub), not correct them. There are a lot of them on the *.txt files and I don't pretend to correct them all. I just want to run the codes that work properly. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: There's no way to do that. You need to find the syntax errors and remove each one. `On Error` only works with _runtime_ errors

Comment: "I have to import some VBA codes (that are written on *.txt files), test them and run them if they're working properly." - If there are syntax errors in the code, the code is not working properly, therefore you haven't been asked to run them.  Set the ones with syntax errors aside and concentrate on testing the ones that will actually run.  (But my gut feeling is that whoever gave you the task is actually expecting you to fix obvious syntax errors, not just ignore them.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! I already thought that wasn't possible and now I'm sure that it can't be done. I will think of something else (maybe a correcting code to prevent syntax errors before running it).

Comment: If you are careful not to ruin anything big and remember to correct your doings, you could comment out the lines that have syntax errors to test the rest part of your code. BUT this only works for the parts that don't destroy essential flow of your code. For example it would be a bad idea to comment out a variable assignment that is used in other parts of code. To be honest, syntax errors are there for a reason and should always be corrected.

Comment: Hello everybody. Actually, I managed to find a way of doing  what I asked you for. Since the syntax errors occurred only on arithmetic code lines, I converted them on Excel Formulas and tested them on a spreadsheet before running the imported script. The  `on error` function works perfectly  on excel syntax errors. Thanks anyway!